# Send message to Numbers stored in Contact of the device in android

Tags: android

I have made app which allows me to send message to multiple user from my device.

Now i want to send message to the person which are stored in My Contact list.
So i want to retrive phone number from my contact list and then i should be able to send message to that particular number..

Any hints how can i go further...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert, but a quick google search brought me to this:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker/